# Running an R expression immediately and again on exit without duplicating the expression

Tags: r

In R, I want to run an expression immediately and then register it to run again when exiting a scope, without writing the expression twice or creating an extra function. Is there a way to achieve this behaviour?

For example, I would like to run some cleanup code at both the beginning and on exit in a function, eg:

```r
unlink(sessions_folder, recursive = TRUE)
on.exit(unlink(sessions_folder, recursive = TRUE))
```

but in one call.

Is there a way to achieve this in base R?

Comment: You could wrap in a function and invoke the function

Comment: was looking for the more barebone and short solution possible

Comment: @akrun I think that wouldn't work because `on.exit` only apply to current function. Wrapping everything including `on.exit` in a new function will execute `on.exit` code on that new function, not the original calling function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a solution with rlang::eval_bare
Unfortunately it does not work with base r "eval", because it doesn't evaluates stack-aware functions like on.exit and parent.frame as expected (see ?rlang::eval_bare)

```r
x <- function()
{
  lapply(list(on.exit, eval), \(x,e) rlang::eval_bare(bquote(.(x)(cat("do cleanup\n"))), e), environment())
  cat("function body\n")
    
}

x()
#> do cleanup
#> function body
#> do cleanup
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's have some example function `.f`.

```r
.f <- function(x) {
    .run_and_run_on_exit(print("hello"))
    print(x * 10)
    print(x * 100)
    .run_and_run_on_exit(print("world"))
}
```

Any time you want the behavior of immediately run an expression and record that expression to execute it again on exit, you use `.run_and_run_on_exit` (the usage is similar to `on.exit`). This `.run_and_run_on_exit` will be the markers that we will use later on to replace with our customized expression.

```r
.run_and_run_on_exit <- function(ff) {
    calling_func <- deparse(sys.call(-1)[[1]])
    stop(sprintf("use transform_func on %s first, for example use_func <- transform_func(%s), then proceed with use_func", calling_func, calling_func), call. = TRUE)
}

transform_func <- function(f) {
    out <- f
    bf <- body(f)
    pos <- grep(".run_and_run_on_exit", bf, fixed = TRUE)
    bf[pos] <- lapply(bf[pos], \(x) {
        substitute({func; on.exit(func, add = TRUE)}, list(func = x[[2]]))
    })
    body(out) <- bf
    
    out
}
```

Test drive:

```r
.f(3) # output error because .f is only acting as a template function
f <- transform_func(.f)
f # print out function f. You can see all the replacement code
#function (x) 
#{
#    {
#        print("hello")
#        on.exit(print("hello"), add = TRUE)
#    }
#    print(x * 10)
#    print(x * 100)
#    {
#        print("world")
#        on.exit(print("world"), add = TRUE)
#    }
#}

f(3)
[1] "hello"
[1] 30
[1] 300
[1] "world"
[1] "hello"
[1] "world"
```